# What's the MIME-Type of TypeScript?

Tags: mime-types, typescript

I want my IIS to correctly display .ts files, is there any MIME-Type for TypeScript? text/javascript or similar may also work, but are there specifications for that?

I already looked up the [language specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) but I didn't find any clue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It would be good to know *why* you want to serve TypeScript files.

As far as I understand, TypeScript is used to compile to Javascript, which is then executed in a browser. Currently, there is no native support for TypeScript (correct me if I'm wrong).

If you still want to serve .ts files via IIS, you can still add a [custom mime-type](http://restpatterns.org/Glossary/MIME_Type) in IIS Admin associated with .ts. The standard defines the prefixes `x.`, `vnd.` and `prs.`, and the vnd. prefix is also listed in the standardized mime types [text/](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html) and [application/](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html).

So, depending on your usage, you might choose `text/x.typescript` or `text/prs.typescript`.

Comment: One very good reason to serve up TypeScript files is when you're using the source mapping feature, and the browser (say, Chrome) needs to download the various original .ts files that went into the .js file that it's actually executing.

Comment: Or for a web typescript editor wich use .d.ts files for syntax checking/autocompletion

Comment: note `x.` was deprecated in favor of the distinction between `prs.` ("I need a mime type for myself") and `vnd.` ("I need a mime type for publishing under my organisation tree")

Comment: @devio Actually, there is another reason you might want to serve TypeScript files. Currently, I am working on a TypeScript project, where the pages are converted to JS at runtime, using ‘transpiler.js’ & Microsoft’s ‘transcriptionService.js’. This allows me to develop TypeScript applications on my iPhone, using the Coda IDE App.

Answer (score 23):

Stick this in your web.config;

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="application/x-typescript" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

[Deno](https://deno.land/) uses `application/typescript` to serve TypeScript files, allowing you to run them with:

```
deno run "https://example.com/file.ts"
```

Comment: What about .tsx files ?

Comment: @softmarshmallow same as `.ts` files it's `application/typescript`

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to comment out `TypeScriptAssetHandler` which converts .ts files to javascript.

```
 <handlers>
    <!--<add name="TypeScriptAssetHandler" path="*.ts" verb="GET" type="BundleTransformer.TypeScript.HttpHandlers.TypeScriptAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.TypeScript" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />-->
  </handlers>
```

You may end up with errors like this if you have this handler defined

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): During the output text content of processed asset an unknown error has occurred.
See more details:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache 2 I simply set the MIME Type to text/plain. This solved my problem where I was getting weird results as in the MIME Type reported was some video format.

You can achieve this with the following in your Apache 2 configuration:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|ts|ts!transpiled)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
AddType text/plain ts
```