# Debug TypeScript in Chrome, 404 response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, typescript

I'm compiling my .TS to JavaScript and generating source maps. However, I can't debug the actual files. I have an X number of .TS files that compiles into CombinedTypescript.js with a source map that is correct.

However, when I try to access my .TS files in the Chrome Debugger, it just gives me a 404 response. The files exist in "Sources", but I can't access them or set breakpoints in CombinedTypescript.js and step through my files.

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you using IIS? You probably have to [add .ts as an mime type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23047088/188246) (or [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

Comment: @DavidSherret I would post that as the answer

Comment: @basarat I didn't want to answer with the assumption they were using IIS, but yeah that's most likely the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Yep, it was the missing Mime type, what a simple fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are having is most likely that IIS isn't configured to serve `.ts` files. You'll need to add `.ts` as an MIME type.

**Option 1 - Edit web.config**

I'd suggest doing this change so that your project will serve `.ts` files regardless of the environment. To do this, add an `mimeMap` tag to your `web.config` under `configuration > system.webServer > staticContent` like so:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="application/x-typescript" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213787/whats-the-mime-type-of-typescript/23047088#23047088)

**Option 2 - Configure IIS**

Another option is to configure IIS to serve `.ts` files. Here are some resources for doing that:

- [How to add an MIME type to a web site (IIS 8)](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)
- [Add MIME Type (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Configure MIME Types (IIS 6)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: you seem to know more here, how can the site work if you cant get the ts..... example i want to see what is behind an event on a button it says ts. but how did it work in the first place. Example github trying to view the source on a button, its linked to https://github.githubassets.com/assets/app/assets/modules/github/behaviors/confirm.ts, the size must get the code from somewhere... but i cant view it.